# Simple way to update form values depending on changes with react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-final-form

I'm trying to implement a form with two consecutive dependent Select with **react-final-form** and **material-ui**

**Requirements**

- Both fields are required
- When user selects a country value

  - city field should reset to blank
  - city field should not be marked as invalid
- User should be able to reset the form completely anytime

**I struggle to find a simple and elegant solution to this requirements with react-final-form** API.

There may be approaches with [mutators](https://medium.com/@erikras/final-form-arrays-and-mutators-13159cb7d285), [react-final-form-listeners](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-listeners), or [decorators](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate) but this seems to me like a common use case of forms for which a simple solution without advanced APIs would be nice.

---

Here is a version with a combination of `FormSpy` component, `useRef` hook and the `form.reset` api.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-material-ui-field-dependencies-hn7ps

- subscribre to form values via FormSpy `onChange` prop
- update a react ref each time values change
- compare ref values with new values and use `form.reset` API to reset city field value without triggering validation

---

Here is another version using **[Declarating Form Rules](https://medium.com/@erikras/declarative-form-rules-c5949ea97366)** approach via `react-final-form-listeners` like Erik adviced to do.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-material-ui-field-dependencies-ijxd0

It is a lot more simpler, as we dont need a react ref, and FormSpy.

---

Both solutions **works almost perfectly** except that the `form.reset` method redefines form `initialValues` under the hood, so that the RESET button **do not reset form to the original `initialValues` anymore**.

Is there a **builtin way to hook in form state changes** and compare old/new values ?

Comment: uoooo this solutions save me a lot of time. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [Declarative Form Rules](https://medium.com/@erikras/declarative-form-rules-c5949ea97366) are what you need?

Comment: I'll give it a try and come back to you. Thank you for your prompt answer Erik

Comment: Here is a modified version with react-final-form-listeners : https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-material-ui-field-dependencies-ijxd0 - 
I ended using this solution in my project, but please note the it still has the downside of modifying original initialValues.

Comment: @Ricovitch it seems not to load the proper city.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa not sure what you mean. The purpose of the sample is not to set the right city depending on the country you choose, but just to implement the requirements i described initially (reset the city field mainly)

Comment: I have another use case. I want to update state so that another component outside the form component knows that a particular value has changed. I tried formspy, but the moment I setState the whole component re-renders